# Taking derivative with respect to $q(z_k)$

Tags: calculus

I want to know why taking derivative of $ \int {q({z_k})\log q({z_k})d{z_k}} $ with respect to $q(z_k)$ will give $\log q(z_k)+1$. Thank you!

**This is a modified question. The original text is at the end of page 6 of this pdf file.** http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf

**The following is a screen capture.**
[image]